# How to properly use NewMessage events in the telethon library in another file

Tags: python, telethon

I have two separate files. My main code is inside the main.py file, and the other part for connecting with Telegram is inside the telegram.py file. I want to write functions to send and receive messages in it. And as a result I can use these functions in my main code.
Sending messages or getting recent messages is very simple according to what I tested and read from the documentation. But my main problem is in using events. For example, in the send_message method, I want to send a message and then wait for a response (the bot may not be available, so I try to send again), but when the message is sent correctly and the bot responds, I don't know how to get that response. and return so that I can use that answer in main.py.
I read in the document that as soon as the message arrives, you can use "client.disconnect"
It was removed from the handler, but in this case, the client is also discounted. That's why I commented them and used remove_event_handler to get out of receiving events.
My main code is as follows:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telegram import Bot
import asyncio

async def main():
    client = TelegramClient(
        session_name,
        api_id,
        api_hash
    )
    await client.connect()

    # main code here and not async
    bot_info = {"username": "somthing"}
    bot = Bot(
        bot_info
    )

    send_message = await bot.send_message(
        client=client,
        message_text="test"
    )
    
    # and other things in main
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

and telegram.py file is:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio


class Bot:
    def __init__(self, bot_info: dict):
        self.bot_info = bot_info
        self.last_id = None

    async def send_message(self, client: TelegramClient, message_text: str, sleep_time_if_bot_not_available: int = 2):
        target_chat = self.bot_info['username']
        message = await client.send_message(target_chat, message_text)
        self.last_id = message.id

        res = None

        @client.on(events.NewMessage(from_users=target_chat))
        async def handle_new_message(event):
            nonlocal res
            if event.is_reply and event.reply_to_msg_id == self.last_id:
                if event.message.text == 'not available':
                    # It waits for a few seconds and sends the message again
                    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time_if_bot_not_available)
                    send_again = await client.send_message(target_chat, message_text)
                    self.last_id = send_again.id
                else:
                    res = event.message
                    client.remove_event_handler(event)
                    # await client.disconnect()

        # await client.run_until_disconnected()
        return res
```

I tested the code like this but "res" always returns None. In general, I had a problem with how to retrieve the last sent message

Comment: You can probably create an `asyncio.Queue` and share it between the two pieces of code. One will put items and the other can read them. However, it really depends a lot on how you plan to structure the code and it's hard to give a definitive answer.